# Kernel Density Estimation using a Two-Boundary-Kernel à la Jones

Tags: kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

I'm trying to understand how to perform a KDE on a bounded support, i.e. with lower and upper boundary, when using a kernel that is specifically designed to ensure consistency/$h^2$-bias at the boundary.
[Jones](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00147776) considered the case of a single lower boundary and suggested a kernel
$$
 K_L(x) = \frac{(a_2(p) - a_1(p)x)K(x)}{a_0(p)a_2(p)-a_1^2(p)}
$$
based on some other kernel $K(x)$ with support [-1, 1] and
$$
 a_l(p) = \int_{-1}^p u^lK(u)\,du .
$$
$K_L(x)$ makes the resulting estimate consistent and reduces the bias at a lower boundary to second order.
The variable $p$ measures the distance to the boundary in multiples of the bandwidth $h$.
I do understand how this $K_L(x)$ comes about.

My question is regarding the appropriate approach for simultaneous lower and upper bound support, $[x_0, x_1]$ of the unknown distribution.
If I didn't miss anything, Jones only gives the hint that $K_L(x)$ quickly becomes very close to $K(x)$ away from the boundary/in the interior, which led me to assume that a fitting kernel might be $K_{L}'(x)$ with
$$
 K_L'(x) = \begin{cases}
     \displaystyle\frac{(a_2(p_1) - a_1(p_1)x)K(x)}{a_0(p_1)a_2(p_1)-a_1^2(p_1)} & \text{if $p_1\le p_2$}\\
     \displaystyle\frac{(a_2(p_2) + a_1(p_2)x)K(x)}{a_0(p_2)a_2(p_2)-a_1^2(p_2)} & \text{if $p_1> p_2$},
    \end{cases}
$$
where $p_1$ and $p_2$ measure the distance to the lower/upper boundary:
$$
 p_1=\frac{x-x_0}{h}\quad\text{and}\quad
 p_2=\frac{x_1-x}{h},
$$
respectively. Here, the case $p1>p2$ reflects the boundary-correct kernel for the upper boundary (hence the different sign).

Is this mathematically feasible (especially since the piece-wise definition is not continuous at $p_1=p_2$ for example when using a normal kernel $K(x)$)?
If so, are there any citable sources I can refer to?